# OneLoginWebScraping - Python3

Tags: python, onelogin

I am trying to log in using a python script, with the intent to scrape some of my data for personal use. I am currently getting a 422 'UNPROCESSABLE CHANGES' message after I try to log in (with script).

I believe I am missing something from my payload. I currently have my email, pass, and the token from the hidden input field. Is there anything else I should be including? Thanks!

Below is my code. This is a combination of a couple approaches. One of which is located here:
https://brennan.io/2016/03/02/logging-in-with-requests/

and here:
http://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/

```
import requests 
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    def cas_login(service, username, password):
    params = {'service':service}
    LOGIN_URL = "https://stmarys-ca.onelogin.com/login"

    # Start session and get login form.
    session = requests.session()
    login = session.get(LOGIN_URL, params=params)

    # Get the hidden elements and put them in our form.
    login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
    hidden_elements = login_html.xpath('//form//input[@type="hidden"]')

    # "Fill out" the form.
    form = {
        "email": str(username),
        "password" : str(password)
    }

    token = {x.attrib['value'] for x in hidden_elements}
    form['authenticity_token'] = token


    # Finally, login and return the session.
    r = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=form, params=params)
    #End of tutorial
    return session,r 

def main():
    response, resp = cas_login('https://www.stmarys-ca.edu/sessions', 'USER_EMAIL', 'USER_PASS')
    print(resp.url)
    print(resp.text)
```

Where USER_EMAIL and USER_PASS are personal information
resp.url returns the login URL and not the service URL included in the parameter
resp.text returns the html page with the error code.

Thoughts? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by fluke, posting answer so others can see.

I added in the following:

```
headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL)
```

to my post request, where LOGIN_URL is the local variable in the code above